# Facebook app's "App Details" page is empty

Tags: facebook

for an app that I just have created a few weeks ago. I now want to upload the graphic assets via the "App Details" page.

But for this app, when i open the "App Details" page, i just see a blank page. I tried Chrome, Firefox, IE, clearing cookies, logging in and out, etc... Nothing helps...

This only happens for this specific app, all other apps on this account show the "App Details" page just fine.

Any ideas what I might do or who I could contact?

Goddchen

Comment: File a bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same happened to me, what i did was to change settings like sandbox mode or setup the options (Website with Facebook Login) and saving this settings. After a couple of times the app details started working again.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the X to temporarily remove the **Mobile Web** section from your app settings it should start working again. When you've updated your App Details, re-enable the **Mobile Web** section.

However, now you will have a new problem because you won't see the mobile options in App Details. Hopefully Facebook will fix this soon.

Answer (score 0):

"App Details" can not contain the app name in the "Tagline" field. Remove the "Tagline", and it will save the details.
Alternatively, try entering the "Tagline" without the app name in that field.
Facebook recognizes that this behavior is "by design".
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/313542868787849